# Asp.Net MVC3 project Controllers and views are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

This is kind of an odd problem that I am facing most of the time. I am creating a website and **I have created a folder inside controllers folder** in the project and I have created a controller inside that folder. So far it was Ok.

Then I created a view for that(**Not manually**)I **can even navigate from controller to view in the code**(This is to tell that the controller and the view are properly mapped in the code). But when I run the project and go to that URL its not working. It gives the following error. Although this is a more general error I have no thread to follow to get out of this mess.

But all the things that are created earlier is working smoothly. I have even tried a Default controller and created a view for that and then ran the program and it gives the same error.

Now I can not create new controllers and views(I can but they are not working). I am stuck with this all day long :(.

I feel like some configuration is missing. But I can not find out.
Since I am new to this I am totally lost. And I can not figure out what to do.

I am totally confused and I have no idea of what has happened.
Is it a settings problem in Visual studio?. And what should I do to make this work.

The error is this:

[image]

PS: I am working with Team Foundation server and I can not even do debugging. These controller methods are not called.

Comment: You started with an empty project, didn't you? As you are new you should use a template for creating a MVC project. I think you are missing the route definitions in the global.asax.

Comment: Have you done any changes to your global.asax file? Seems like broken routing...

Comment: What happens if you create a new project (ASP.NET MVC - Internet application) and run it. Does it work?

Comment: Interesting,, Yeah I am working in a team. That I have to deal with. :(. Can you please help me to replace what is missing. Thanks a lot

Comment: @LukeP new projects are working fine. I checked that too.. :(

Comment: @walther: No I have not changed any in the global.asax.

Comment: @Diode, you MUST have changed something though... Maybe show us the relevant parts of the code + url you're testing for? You said you're working in a team - can't they give you a hint of what you've done wrong? They have a full access to the source code I suppose, so it might be 1000 times faster than waiting for an answer here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into [MVC routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) and modify your **Global.asax.cs** with this code:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```